# vim 8: C++ syntax highlighting has some minor fault

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, plugin-system, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-ale

I'm using vim 8 to code C++11.

I've installed the vim plugins: YCM, ALE, [vim-code-dark](https://github.com/tomasiser/vim-code-dark) and [vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight](https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight), however, it seems that there is some error on syntax highlighting.

[image]

As you see, `scene` and `arg` are highlighted with yellow, but they are variables, which shouldn't be highlighted, just like `isColor`, it seems that both of them are regarded as functions, I think the reason is the way of initialization: `string arg("XXX");`. It seems that this kind of initialization is regarded as a declaration of function, instead of a variable.

I don't know who is controlling this mechanism. Is it vim 8? or the vim plugins, such as YCM, ALE?

Is there some way to fix this error?

Comment: You’ll probably need to talk to the relevant plugin author. We have a handy question about debugging to find out where it’s coming from. The general idea is to start clean and try plugins one at a time until you find a combo that triggers it. I would bet it’s either enhanced highlight or vim defaults though. https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks. Well, I just removed `vim-code-dark` and `vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight`, all becomes white except the C++ keywords. Then I added `vim-code-dark` back, it only changed the colors of the C++ keywords. So I think this issue comes from `vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble But , in vim 7, `vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight` can not highlight the custom class name (`SysTool` in this example), so I think vim 8 do something too. So you are right about "either enhanced highlight or vim 8"...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Well, it seems that this issue is not a piece of cake... :D

Comment: Try `let g:cpp_no_function_highlight = 1` ? That will disable highlighting of user defined functions... Yes it will disable more than these two cases, but maybe that's acceptable to you?

Comment: The match for custom function is way too simple, simply looks at a word followed by a `(` and that's it: https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight/blob/master/after/syntax/cpp.vim#L39 perhaps disabling it makes sense...

Comment: OTOH, I believe in modern C++ you can use `Scene scene{cols, lines};` and `std::string arg{argv[1]};`, right?

Comment: `Syntax` is one of the most complicate stuff in `vim`, `c++` is one of the most complicate programming language,  two complicate stuff add together is too complicate.  Let it go. I use `vim-cpp-enchanced-highlight` too, I see highlight mistake from time to time. Just let it go, it wont matter too much.

Comment: @dedowsdi   lol, I agree, let it go~

Comment: @filbranden   Good, let me disable it.